# how to make gnome show by default hidden files

Tags: linux, gnome

How can I make gnome show by default the hidden files in desktop environment?
It's a pain to click every time `show hidden files` button.

I need it to show the hidden files automatically like in windows.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/746212/376050) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is not displaying at all that `Show hidden and backup files` checkbox. Probably because this is a newer version of GNOME, I think it's GNOME2

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Gnome, it can be done with dconf-editor, setting this to "`true`": `/org/gtk/gtk4/settings/file-chooser/show-hidden`